# Escape characters not working when extracted from JSON

Tags: python, json

I am trying to build a very simple code SQL code formatter, which extracts the query from a JSON object and the goal is to copy the final output to the clipboard. I have not got to the clipboard part yet, because I could not get Python to interpret escape characters.

`print` function prints the whole thing with escape characters and all, and I cannot figure out why.

```py
import json

main_query = {"text": "SELECT\n  * from test          where id = 1\n    LIMIT 10"}

query = str(json.dumps(main_query['text']).strip('"'))

print(query) # Not working
print('{}'.format(query)) # Not working either

"""
Output:

SELECT\n  * from test          where id = 1\n    LIMIT 10
SELECT\n  * from test          where id = 1\n    LIMIT 10
"""
```

Comment: json doesn't support new lines, so my guess is that `json.dumps` automatically escape newline characters. You may want to do a `replace("\\n", "\n")` on the result string. (and unfortunately that may give some bug in situation where you have somehting like "division by n" in your SQL code ... Or you can stop using `json.dumps` for that. It's not clear why you are using it (see baduker's asnwer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
main_query = {"text": "SELECT\n  * from test          where id = 1\n    LIMIT 10"}
print(main_query["text"])
SELECT
  * from test          where id = 1
    LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This does the trick. I would have thought it would yield the same result if it had come to my mind. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's also important to understand why this happens.

When you do *[json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps)* on a string you get the **representation** of the string.

For example, if you do `print(repr(main_query["text]))`, you'll get this output:

```
SELECT \n  * from test          where id = 1 \n    LIMIT 10
```

However, there's no need to do [*repr()*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html) or *json.dumps* over a string that has newlines and you want for these newlines to be printed as such.

If you only do:

```
import json

main_query = {"text": "SELECT \n  * from test          where id = 1 \n    LIMIT 10"}

query = main_query['text'].strip('"')

print(query)
```

You'll get the string as you want:

```
SELECT
  * from test          where id = 1
    LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import re
main_query = {"text": "SELECT\n  * from test          where id = 1\n    LIMIT 10"}
query = main_query['text']
print(re.sub('\n',' ',query))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this buddy, Lists and Loop Print implementation

```
import json
main_query = {"text": "SELECT\n  * from test          where id = 1\n    LIMIT 10"}
query = str(json.dumps(main_query['text']).strip('"'))
for word in query.split('\\n'):
  print(word)
```